# unresolved sedis dependency with play-plugin for redis

Tags: playframework, redis, playframework-2.0

I am using play framework v2.2.1 and have the following in my build.sbt file.

**resolvers:**

```
   Resolver.url("play-redis", url("http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play-plugins-redis_2.9.1/2.0/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
```

**libraryDependencies**

```
  "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-redis" % "2.1.1",
   "org.sedis" %% "sedis" % "1.1.8",
```

I have tried with and without the sedis option in libraryDependencies.  When I run play dependencies, I keep getting the following error:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.sedis#sedis_2.10.0:1.1.1: not found
```

Any ideas on troubleshooting/fixing this will be greatly appreciated.  If not, I will just go ahead with an unmanaged dependency.

**Edit**:
I forgot to mention that I also added the following to my play.plugins file:

**play.plugins**

```
550:com.typesafe.plugin.RedisPlugin
```

However, the issue is still pending.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working :
In the *build.sbt* file :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-redis" % "2.2.1"
)

resolvers += "Sedis repository" at "http://pk11-scratch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/"
```

Answer (score 0):

What a mess with different versions : play-plugins-redis 2.0 in scala 2.9.1 in Resolver but 2.1.1 in libraryDependencies and error log shows scala 2.10.0, sedis in 1.1.8 in libraryDependecies but 1.1.1 in the error log....)

First, the Resolver must not have the version in it (I assume the syntax is correct even if I am not sure about the ivy pattern):

```
Resolver.url("play-redis", url("http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Second, this repository doesn't have sedis for scala 2.10, you have to add another resolver :

```
Resolver.url("play-redis", url("http://pk11-scratch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Third, sedis is already a dependency of play-plugins-redis, you should not to include it in your dependencies (or make sure it is the same version)

Comment: syntax is correct - I wasted some time with different versions and gave up for the time being.  Will re-check and update here